# apache avro with short messages

Tags: apache, rdf, avro

Each data message is approx 1k bytes in size.

Schema is approx 2k bytes of (unchanging) RDF.

Is there an efficient way to use Avro that does not triple the size of the data flow?

TIA,

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to use Avro with the above data & schema size contraints so that each message will be closer to its 1k byte data size.  My understanding is that Avro requires the schema to be sent with the data for each message.  Switching to Avro would thus triple the data flow and would be impractical.  Regrettably, my customer wants "everything" standardized with Avro.  So, I'm seeking knowledge if there is a way to use Avro without paying the price of sending the schema, which seems like it ought to be possible given that the schema will not change.  Thanks for your reply,

Comment: I *think* that you can do what you want to do.  The [1.7.6 documentation](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/) says "When Avro is used in RPC, the client and server exchange schemas in the connection handshake. **(This can be optimized so that, for most calls, no schemas are actually transmitted.)** Since both client and server both have the other's full schema, correspondence between same named fields, missing fields, extra fields, etc. can all be easily resolved."